# Infinispan limitations to Cache value objects

Tags: java, caching, infinispan

I am wondering if there any limitations for the value of Infinispan's Cache? Say for Cache value, can I store a complex data structure such as a Map?

E.g. `Cache<String, Map<String, MyObject>>`

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Since performance is a very important factor in this process, Infinispan uses JBoss Marshalling framework instead of standard Java Serialization in order to marshall/unmarshall Java POJOs.

You can find more information in the [User Guide](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#marshalling)

Comment: Starting with Infinispan 9.2 there's also a [Multi Map API](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#multimap_cache) for embedded Infinispan. This could be useful for the type of data mentioned above.